# Call a view with render in Phoenix Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In [my](https://github.com/loretoparisi/phoenix-elixir-boilerplate) Phoenix/Elixir boilerplate web app I have the typical structure described [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/adding_pages.html),  where the simple `HelloController` uses a HelloView component to render the templates in the `hello/` folder. This works ok.
Now let's say I want to add the `snake_view.ex` View component [here](https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/60a5705482d26326675c7b752ed0dacd). This View depends on `Phoenix` [LiveView](https://dockyard.com/blog/2018/12/12/phoenix-liveview-interactive-real-time-apps-no-need-to-write-javascript) and acts slightly different than other ordinary views, that render templates, since it has a `render` method in it among the other functions:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.SnakeView do
  use Phoenix.LiveView
   # ..
   def render(%{game_state: :over} = assigns) do
   # ..
```

Now, after adding the `LiveView` dependency, I have added a route in `router.ex`

```
get "/snake", SnakeController, :index
```

But now I do not know how to reference the `SnakeView` from this new `SnakeController`:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.SnakeController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn)
  end
end
```

The error I get when heading to [http://localhost:4000/snake](http://localhost/snake) is

```
function HelloWeb.SnakeView.render/2 is undefined or private
```

so it seems that from the router the `SnakeController` has been invoked, and the `SnakeView` as well, but something is wrong.

**[UPDATE]**

I have realized that there were a lot of things I was missing to do before make it working the Phoenix `LiveView` within the PhoenixFramework WebApp:

1. Endpoint `endpoint.ex`. You need to add a

   ```
   socket "/live", Phoenix.LiveView.Socket
   ```
2. Router `router.ex`. Add a route to the `LiveView` via the `PageController`:

   ```
   get "/snake", PageController, :snake
   ```
3. In the `PageController` add a def for the `snake` function:

   ```
      def snake(conn, _) do
          conn
          |> put_layout(:game)
          |> LiveView.Controller.live_render(HelloWeb.SnakeLive, session: %{})
        end
   ```
4. WebApp `your_app_web.ex`. Add in `view` def the

   ```
   import Phoenix.LiveView, only: [live_render: 2, live_render: 3]
   ```
5. Config in `configs.exs`. Add a `LiveView` salt token:

   ```
   live_view: [
       signing_salt: "YOUR_LIVEVIEW_TOKEN"
    ]
   ```
6. Add a `live` folder in your `your_app_web` web app folder. Put your `LiveView` view there.
7. Add the WebSocket connection in the main `app.js` file:

   ```
       import {LiveSocket, debug} from "phoenix_live_view"
       let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live")
       liveSocket.connect()
   ```
8. Added css resources: `live_view.css`, `snake.css`, imported in `app.css` the new css:

   ```
       @import "./phoenix.css";
       @import "./live_view.css";
       @import "./snake.css";
   ```

The resulting WebApp structure should now be:

```
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── live_view.css
│   │   ├── phoenix.css
│   │   └── snake.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   └── socket.js
├── config
│   ├── config.exs
├── lib
│   ├── hello
│   │   └── application.ex
│   ├── hello.ex
│   ├── hello_web
│   │   ├── channels
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── endpoint.ex
│   │   ├── gettext.ex
│   │   ├── live
│   │   ├── router.ex
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   └── views
│   └── hello_web.ex
```

At this stage, when pointing the browser to http://localhost:4000/snake
I get the LiveView partially working:

[image]

Please check the full code [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/phoenix-elixir-boilerplate) to investigate this issue.

Comment: `render/2` ->  2 arguments

Comment: @m3characters thanks I have cleaned up the examples, and fixed most of the issues, but it is still not working completely. See the github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of this page - https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view - there's at least one step that I'm not seeing in your code.

```
// assets/js/app.js
import LiveSocket from "phoenix_live_view"

let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live")
liveSocket.connect()
```

Perhaps add that and confirm that you have the rest of the steps covered as well. Hopefully that works :)

Comment: good point, let me have a look. This is the web socket client part, it makes sense!

Comment: So, I have added the missing client web socket connect part and other client-side parts missing (css, html): https://github.com/loretoparisi/phoenix-elixir-boilerplate/blob/master/assets/js/app.js. It is still not working though.

Comment: I cloned your repo locally and it works just fine after installing dependencies and so on. Perhaps you haven't pressed one of the arrow keys yet ? It's the trigger to start the game.

Comment: Yes I finally was able to make it working, adding more steps! Thanks accepting your answer.